# how to combine append() and replaceWith() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, append, replacewith

Is ther a Jquery way to combine `append()` and `replaceWith()`?

I have a login form in a JQM project, sitting on every site. As multiple pages will be loaded into the DOM, I need to move the long form "along", as the user goes from page to page, to avoid having duplicate form#ids in the DOM.

My question: 
I can do like this:

```
 $('.form_in_new_page').replaceWith('.form_in_old_page')
```

But is there a way to **"append and replace"**, so I can do this with one line of code?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT: some more info**
Here is my script which I'm running on pagebeforehide:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page").basePage').on('pagebeforehide', function(e, data) {

     // look for unique elements on the page being left
     $(this).find(':jqmData(unique="true")').each(function(){

         var uniqueID = $(this).jqmData("unique-id"),
             nextPage = data.nextPage,
             nextUnique = nextPage.find( ":jqmData(unique-id='"+uniqueID+"')" ),
             nextUniqueID = nextUnique.jqmData('unique-id') === uniqueID;

         // if a unique element with id=123 is on both from and next page
         if ( nextUniqueID == true ) {
             // append element from page being left to and replace it on next page
             nextUnique.replaceWith( $(this) );
             }
     });       
  });
```

I need to keep my pages inside the DOM in my app. All pages have a login/logout popup, which includes a form and inputs with ids. So if I have 10 pages in my DOM I will have 10 popups with 10 forms and 10x each ID. I'm inserting the popups automatically on every so they are there if the user calls a subpage directly. However as soons as the user goes to the next page I need to make sure the form on the first page **appends and replaces** the form on the 2nd page.

Hope it's clear now.

The above only replaces the form on the new page, but still leaves it in the old page.

Comment: Why not put it in the layout?

Comment: What do you want to get out of `.append()` that you're not getting out of `.relplaceWith()`?

Comment: _"But is there a way to "append and replace", so I can do this with one line of code?"_ - You've only shown one line of code so far, so it's a bit hard to make that any shorter. Please show more of your code to make it clearer what you want to do.

Comment: @nnnnnn - sorry. you are right. 4am question... Above is a little more detail.

Comment: @Jasper - I need to move an element from A to B = append and replace what's inside B with A = replaceWith

Answer (score 1):

In jquery since functions return this ($) you can chain calls:

```
$("#selector").replaceWith("<div>Hello</div>").append('<div>test2</div>');
```

Of corse, that means you need to chain calls in the correct order.

Comment: That's not _nesting_, it's _chaining_.

Comment: You can do empty then append